# How do I aggregate numbers from a string column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate

I am dealing with a poorly designed database column which has values like this

```
ID  cid   Score
1    1    3 out of 3
2    1    1 out of 5
3    2    3 out of 6
4    3    7 out of 10
```

I want the aggregate sum and percentage of Score column grouped on cid like this

```
cid    sum            percentage
1      4 out of 8       50
2      3 out of 6       50
3      7 out of 10      70
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Redesign the table. How hard is it to split the column into two?

Comment: Absolutely agree, but I need a quick fix until I do so, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
select
  t.cid
  , cast(sum(s.a) as varchar(5)) + 
      ' out of ' + 
      cast(sum(s.b) as varchar(5)) as sum
  , ((cast(sum(s.a) as decimal))/sum(s.b))*100 as percentage
from MyTable t
  inner join 
  (select
    id
    , cast(substring(score,0,2) as Int) a
    , cast(substring(score,charindex('out of', score)+7,len(score)) as int) b
   from MyTable
   ) s on s.id = t.id
group by t.cid
```

[[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d37d/13)]

Answer (score 0):

Redesign the table, but on-the-fly as a CTE. Here's a solution that's not as short as you could make it, but that takes advantage of the handy SQL Server function PARSENAME. You may need to tweak the percentage calculation if you want to truncate rather than round, or if you want it to be a decimal value, not an int.

In this or most any solution, you have to count on the column values for Score to be in the very specific format you show. If you have the slightest doubt, you should run some other checks so you don't miss or misinterpret anything.

```
with
P(ID, cid, Score2Parse) as (
  select
    ID,
    cid,
    replace(Score,space(1),'.')
  from scores
),
S(ID,cid,pts,tot) as (
  select
    ID,
    cid,
    cast(parsename(Score2Parse,4) as int),
    cast(parsename(Score2Parse,1) as int)
  from P
)
  select
    cid, cast(round(100e0*sum(pts)/sum(tot),0) as int) as percentage
  from S
  group by cid;
```